# MERGE will not work on production server as it is still SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-merge

I have the following script which works on our SQL Server 2016, but throws the following error on production, which unfortunately is still running SQL Server 2012:

> Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spUpdateAlertHourlyCounts, Line 62
> Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spUpdateAlertHourlyCounts, Line 63
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

The script is:

```
USE [AutoTicketDB_Test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      Mych
-- Create date: 15/01/2024
-- Description: Script that will grab the hourly alert incidents count for a particular date and save this to the Alert_HourlyCounts table
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateAlertHourlyCounts] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @DateForData DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ThisDate DATE
    SET @ThisDate = CAST(Convert(varchar(10), @DateForData,120) As DATE);

    DECLARE @StartDate varchar(10); 
    SET @StartDate = CONVERT(varchar(10), @ThisDate, 126);
    PRINT 'StartDate = ' + @StartDate;

    DECLARE @EndDate nvarchar(10);
    SET @EndDate = CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ThisDate), 126);
    PRINT 'EndDate = ' + @EndDate;

    -- This statement will get the hourly data for a given date and store this data in a temporary table
    SELECT @StartDate As AlertDate, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 00:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 01:00:00', 120)), 0) As H00, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 01:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 02:00:00', 120)), 0) As H01, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 02:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 03:00:00', 120)), 0) As H02, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 03:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 04:00:00', 120)), 0) As H03, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 04:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 05:00:00', 120)), 0) As H04, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 05:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 06:00:00', 120)), 0) As H05, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 06:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 07:00:00', 120)), 0) As H06, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 07:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 08:00:00', 120)), 0) As H07, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 08:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 09:00:00', 120)), 0) As H08, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 09:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 10:00:00', 120)), 0) As H09, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 10:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 11:00:00', 120)), 0) As H10, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 11:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 12:00:00', 120)), 0) As H11, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 12:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 13:00:00', 120)), 0) As H12, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 13:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 14:00:00', 120)), 0) As H13, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 14:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 15:00:00', 120)), 0) As H14, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 15:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 16:00:00', 120)), 0) As H15, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 16:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 17:00:00', 120)), 0) As H16, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 17:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 18:00:00', 120)), 0) As H17, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 18:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 19:00:00', 120)), 0) As H18, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 19:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 20:00:00', 120)), 0) As H19, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 20:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 21:00:00', 120)), 0) As H20, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 21:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 22:00:00', 120)), 0) As H21, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 22:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 23:00:00', 120)), 0) As H22, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Count(ID) FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests] WHERE snIncidentCreated BETWEEN Convert(datetime, @StartDate + ' 23:00:00', 120) AND Convert(datetime, @EndDate + ' 00:00:00', 120)), 0) As H23
    INTO #tempAlertHourlyCount
    FROM [dbo].[ALERT_Requests]
    GROUP BY [Alert_source]


    --This statement will check if there is already a row for the date the data was collected. 
    --If there is already a row then the row is updated with the new data
    --If the date does not exist the new data is inserted as a new row.
    MERGE INTO dbo.Alert_HourlyCounts AS target
    USING (SELECT AlertDate, H00, H01, H02, H03, H04, H05, H06, H07, H08, H09, H10, H11, H12, H13, H14, H15, H16, H17, H18, H19, H20, H21, H22, H23 from #tempAlertHourlyCount) AS source
    ON (target.AlertDate = source.AlertDate)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET H00 = source.H00, H01 = source.H01, H02 = source.H02, H03 = source.H03, H04 = source.H04, H05 = source.H05, H06 = source.H06, H07 = source.H07, 
                   H08 = source.H08, H09 = source.H09, H10 = source.H10, H11 = source.H11, H12 = source.H12, H13 = source.H13, H14 = source.H14, H15 = source.H15, 
                   H16 = source.H16, H17 = source.H17, H18 = source.H18, H19 = source.H19, H20 = source.H20, H21 = source.H21, H22 = source.H22, H23 = source.H23
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (AlertDate, H00, H01, H02, H03, H04, H05, H06, H07, H08, H09, H10, H11, H12, H13, H14, H15, H16, H17, H18, H19, H20, H21, H22, H23) 
        VALUES (source. AlertDate, source.H00, source.H01, source.H02, source.H03, source.H04, source.H05, source.H06, source.H07, 
                source.H08, source.H09, source.H10, source.H11, source.H12, source.H13, source.H14, source.H15, 
                source.H16, source.H17, source.H18, source.H19, source.H20, source.H21, source.H22, source.H23);

    --This statement will dispose of the temporary table
    DROP TABLE #tempAlertHourlyCount

END
GO
```

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL Server 2012? We will be upgrading this server to SQL Server 2019 but not in time.

Comment: No, there is no way to make a server that does not support a specific feature magically support that specific feature.

Comment: `MERGE` is supported on SQL Server 2012 though, it was added in SQL Server 2008. What compatibility level is your database set to (and why is it 90 (SQL Server 2005) or lower)?

Comment: Just don't use merge in any version, you can always make do with a separate update + insert combo, especially for simple things like that one you have

Comment: For more on @siggemannen 's comment, see: https://sqlblog.org/merge.

Comment: Side note - your code will be simpler and perform better if you use conditional aggregation rather than all those subqueries

Comment: You gain nothing by using MERGE. You don't even reduce the line count. MERGE isn't even atomic, only the separate INSERT and UPDATE steps are. You still need an explicit transaction to ensure consistent results. What you try to do is the same as an `UPDATE Alert_HourlyCounts  .... FROM tempAlertHourlyCount INNER JOIN Alert_HourlyCounts  ` followed by an `INSERT Alert_HourlyCounts FROM tempAlertHourlyCount 
 LEFT JOIN Alert_HourlyCounts ... WHERE Alert_HourlyCounts.Date IS NULL`

Comment: You can also use `PIVOT` https://dbfiddle.uk/Dk4pDTnd

Comment: Many thanks for the comments. On checking with others on the team this database was migrated from SQL2005 and therefore may well be set to it's compatibility level. I have amended my script to use an UPDATE - If @@ROWCOUNT = 0 then an INSERT

Comment: hmm, but what if you have more than 1 row of data? then @@rowcount will be > 0 but you might have rows to insert still? You should use INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't update the compatibility level, @Mych ? Do you have code that will break if you change it to level 110? *I'm struggling to remember any breaking changes that were added in 2008/2012 that are avoided by compatibility levels. ANSI-89 support was* removed *in SQL Server 2012, so not even compatibility levels will avoid that.*

Comment: Actually I did miss in the `PIVOT` that `Alert_source` also needs to be projected in the CTE as this is a grouping column  - so @siggemannen's point is correct that there will be a row per alert source

Comment: Ah I see why I missed it. Your subqueries aren't even correlated to that so are presumably returning the wrong thing - or you shouldn't have had that `GROUP BY` in the first place and there was no need for the outer select against `[dbo].[ALERT_Requests]`

Comment: @siggemannen You have a point but in this case the #tempAlertTable will only ever contain one row - basically an hourly count for a specified date. This sp will be run as a SQLJob probably every half hour to update the counts throughout the day.

Comment: As it currently stands (with the code posted in the question) it will contain as many rows as you have distinct AlertSources in `ALERT_Requests` - all with the same values

Comment: @ThomA I have asked out main DBA to investigate whether the compatibility level can be returned to 2012 level. But, as others have mentioned I'm not gaining much by using MERGE over the now working UPDATE  if @@ROWCOUNT = 0 then INSERT

Comment: Yes, I agree with others than an Upsert is a better solution to a `MERGE`, but there are plenty of other features that are added in 2008 and 2012 that you are missing out on, @Mych ; that you have been (correctly) persuaded to not use `MERGE` doesn't mean you shouldn't be getting that compatibility level raised.

Comment: @MartinSmith I have a GROUP BY - (AlertSource is the same in all rows) which means my initial select will only create one row in the #temp table. It may not be the best SQL (I'm more an app developer so my SQL skills are not that advanced. I noted your comment about conditional aggregation in place of individual subqueries. I'm reading up on that now to see how to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by trying an update first if now rows affected then I do an insert.

```
UPDATE dbo.Alert_HourlyCounts SET H00 = t.H00, H01 = t.H01, H02 = t.H02, H03 = t.H03, H04 = t.H04, H05 = t.H05, H06 = t.H06, H07 = t.H07, 
                                H08 = t.H08, H09 = t.H09, H10 = t.H10, H11 = t.H11, H12 = t.H12, H13 = t.H13, H14 = t.H14, H15 = t.H15, 
                                H16 = t.H16, H17 = t.H17, H18 = t.H18, H19 = t.H19, H20 = t.H20, H21 = t.H21, H22 = t.H22, H23 = t.H23 
                                FROM dbo.Alert_HourlyCounts As o
                                JOIN #tempAlertHourlyCount t ON o.AlertDate = t.AlertDate

-- the AlertDate does not exist the the @@ROWCOUNT will be 0 so we do an Insert
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Alert_HourlyCounts (AlertDate, H00, H01, H02, H03, H04, H05, H06, H07, H08, H09, H10, H11, H12, H13, H14, H15, H16, H17, H18, H19, H20, H21, H22, H23)
    SELECT AlertDate, H00, H01, H02, H03, H04, H05, H06, H07, H08, H09, H10, H11, H12, H13, H14, H15, H16, H17, H18, H19, H20, H21, H22, H23 FROM #tempAlertHourlyCount
END;

--This statement will dispose of the temporary table
DROP TABLE #tempAlertHourlyCount
```